# Api .net Que el atributo Id del model no se muestre en el Post

Tags: api, .net, swagger

tengo un problema, hice una api en .net 6 y tengo un modelo User, con un Id incremental.
Yo quiero que cuando en swagger haga un get de un user, me muestre todos los datos (incluido el Id), pero si hago un Post no quiero que en el body aparezca el Id. Como puedo hacer?

```
 public class User
        {

            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            public string Email { get; set; }

            public string Password { get; set; }

        }
        
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class UserController : ControllerBase
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public IActionResult Get()
            {
                try
                {
                    List<User>? user;
                    using (Context context = new())
                    {

                        user = context.Users.ToList();
                    }

                    return Ok(user.ToList());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return BadRequest(e.Message);
                }
            }

       
            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Post(User value)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (Context context = new())
                    {

                        context.Users.Add(value);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                        return Ok();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return BadRequest(e.Message);

                }

            }
```

[image: Swagger, el Id en el post no se debe requerir]

Comment: No entiendo.. cuando haces un post tenes que mandar User.. y user tiene el id... vos queres mandar entonces otra clase que no tenga el id?? y en ese caso, el contexto como va a saber que cosas actualizar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la clase User debes poner el decorador [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)], esto le dirá al swagger que es de solo lectura

```
public class User
    {

        [Key]
        [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

Luego debes configurar el Swagger, en el program.cs de esta manera

```
 builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(a=>a.EnableAnnotations());
```

Resultados:

GET

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

POST

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona perfecto, después caí en cuenta que en lo que hice yo el Get no trae el Id.

Comment: Justo lo que buscaba, mlo habia probado pero omiti configurar el swagger

Answer (score 1):

Creo que era esto a lo que te referías que tu Id es autoincremento y no querías que te saliera en el **body** a la hora de hacer el post porque se supone ira cambiando solo a medida que se introducen mas registros.

Lo resuelve utilizando el **Data Annotation** `[JsonIgnore]`

```
public class Prueba
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

***Swagger***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Response***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***SqlServer***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema con el JsonIgnore es que cuando hago un Get no retorna el id, y en el get lo necesito, no lo quiero en el Post

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que lo que estás buscando es un Request distinto para tu Post. Te propongo que hagas lo siguiente:

Crea una nueva clase para el Request del Post llamada NewUserDTO:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego modifica tu post de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El uso de DTO en los Requests te ayuda a solicitar solo los datos requeridos.

Comment: Esta sería la verdadera respuesta correcta. No tiene sentido modificar el swagger para que no saque tu id, cuando realmente nunca deberíamos estar sacando las clases internas de nuestras API al público, si no un DTO tal como hace esta respuesta. +1 por buena práctica!